# PHP website Optimization

Tags: php, performance, caching, optimization

I have a high traffic website and I need make sure my site is fast enough to display my pages to everyone rapidly.

I searched on Google many articles about speed and optimization and here's what I found:

- Cache the page
- Save it to the disk

**Caching the page in memory:**

This is very fast but if I need to change the content of my page I have to remove it from cache and then re-save the file on the disk.

**Save it to disk**

This is very easy to maintain but every time the page is accessed I have to read on the disk.

Which method should I go with?

Comment: You should add more details about your website : os, server, cms ?...etc

Comment: i use apache+php+mysql+centos - no cms or framework

Comment: what type of hosting you have? shared? dedicated?

Comment: i have a dedicate server

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Jan & idm are right but here's how to:

Caching (pages or contents) is crutial for performance. The minimum calls you request to the database or the file system is better whether if your content is static or dynamic.

You can use a PHP accelerator if you need to run dynamic content:

My recommendation is to use [Alternative PHP Cache (APC)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php)

*Here's some benchmark:*

[What is the best PHP accelerator to use?](http://agilewebmasters.com/robert/what-is-the-best-php-accelerator-to-use/)

[PHP Accelerators : APC vs Zend vs XCache with Zend Framework](http://blog.digitalstruct.com/2007/12/23/php-accelerators-apc-vs-zend-vs-xcache-with-zend-framework/)

[Lighttpd – PHP Acceleration Benchmarks](http://blog.bodhizazen.net/linux/lighttpd-php-acceleration-benchmarks/)

**For caching content and even pages you can use: [Memcached](http://memcached.org/) or [Redis](http://redis.io/).**

**Memcached:**
Free & open source, high-performance, distributed memory object caching system, generic in nature, but intended for use in speeding up dynamic web applications by alleviating database load. Memcached is an in-memory key-value store for small chunks of arbitrary data (strings, objects) from results of database calls, API calls, or page rendering.

**Redis**
Redis is an open source, advanced key-value store. It is often referred to as a data structure server since keys can contain strings, hashes, lists, sets and sorted sets.

Both are very good tool for caching contents or variables.

*Here's some benchmark and you can choose which one you prefer:*

[Redis vs Memcached](http://trespams.com/2011/08/05/redis-vs-memcached-en/)

[Redis vs Memcached](http://systoilet.wordpress.com/2010/08/09/redis-vs-memcached/)

[Redis VS Memcached (slightly better bench)](http://dormando.livejournal.com/525147.html)

[On Redis, Memcached, Speed, Benchmarks and The Toilet](http://antirez.com/post/redis-memcached-benchmark.html)

**You can install also [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/), [nginx](http://nginx.org/), or [G-Wan](http://gwan.ch/)**

**Varnish**:
Varnish is an HTTP accelerator designed for content-heavy dynamic web sites. In contrast to other HTTP accelerators, such as Squid, which began life as a client-side cache, or Apache, which is primarily an origin server, Varnish was designed from the ground up as an HTTP accelerator.

**nginx**
nginx (pronounced ?engine-x?) is a lightweight, high-performance Web server/reverse proxy and e-mail (IMAP/POP3) proxy, licensed under a BSD-like license. It runs on Unix, Linux, BSD variants, Mac OS X, Solaris, and Microsoft Windows.

**g-wan**
G-WAN is a Web server with ANSI C scripts and a Key-Value store which outperform all other solutions.

*Here's some benchmark and you can choose which one you prefer:*

[Serving static files: a comparison between Apache, Nginx, Varnish and G-WAN](http://nbonvin.wordpress.com/2011/03/14/apache-vs-nginx-vs-varnish-vs-gwan/)

[Web Server Performance Benchmarks](http://loadstorm.com/2011/web-server-performance-benchmarks)

[Nginx+Varnish compared to Nginx](http://www.go2linux.org/linux/2011/04/nginx-varnish-compared-nginx-941)

[Apache, Varnish, nginx and lighttpd](http://cd34.com/blog/infrastructure/apache-varnish-nginx-and-lighttpd/)

[G-WAN vs Nginx](http://www.wikivs.com/wiki/G-WAN_vs_Nginx)

Comment: i use nginx + redis and they are super fast +1 for the answer

Answer (score 4):

You have a good idea, which is close to what i do myself. If i have a page that is 100% static, i'll save a html version of it and serve that to the user instead of generating the content again every time. This saves both mysql queries and several io operations in some cases. Every time i make some change, my administration interface simply removes the html file and recreates it.

This method has proven to be around 100x faster on my server.

Comment: This is one of the best caching methods, just recreate the static html page on changes.

Comment: This process could be automated quite easily.

Answer (score 3):

The big question with website performance is "do you serve static pages, or do you serve dynamic pages?".

**Static pages**

The best way to speed up static pages is to cache them outside your website. If you can afford to, serve them from a CDN (Akamai, Cotendo, Level3). In this case, the traffic never hits your site. There are several ways to control the cache - from fixed duration to the standard HTTP cache directives.

Even if you can't serve your HTML from a CDN, storing your images, javascript and other static assets on a CDN can speed up your site - you could use a cloud service like Amazon for this.

If you can't afford a CDN for your HTML, you could use your own caching proxy layer, as book of Zeus suggests. I've had good results with Varnish. Ideally, you'd run your caching proxy on its own hardware - but you can run it on your existing servers.

**Dynamic pages**

Dynamic pages are harder to cache - so then you need to concentrate on making the pages themselves as efficient as possible. This basically means hunting the bottleneck - in most systems, the bottleneck is the database (but by no means always).

If you're confident your bottleneck is the database, there are several ways caching options - you can cache "snippets" of HTML, or you can cache database queries. Using an accelerator helps with this - I wouldn't invent one from scratch. This probably means re-architecting (parts of) your application.

Answer (score 2):

You have to profile your site first.

Instead of wild guess one have to determine certain bottleneck(s) and then solve that certain problem.

Cahing is not a silver bullet nor a synonym for the optimization.
Sometimes caching is not applicable (for the ads, for example), sometimes it will help nothing as the reason of ht site slowness may be in some unrelated spot.
Your site may run out of memory. So, memory caching will make the things worse.

I can't believe someone has a high traffic site and said nmot a word of the prior profiling. How can you run it knowing nothing of it's internals? CPU load, memory load, disk i/o and such.

Answer (score 1):

I can add:

- Cache everything you can
- Minimize number of includes
- Use accelerator

Please, investigate, what makes your site slow. Don't forget about YSlow and similar things, they can help you a lot.

Besides, if you have heavy calculations you could write php extension for them, but i don't think this is your case